# SVN per repo authentication

Tags: svn, authentication

I have several repos and have set a password for all the users in `/etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd` with htpasswd command. I would like to set per repo authentication for every single repository. By the way, not all members should have access for all the repos.

I have also set the passwd files for every repos.

Comment: Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81361/how-to-setup-access-control-in-svn

Answer (score 0):

Read, understand and use Path-Based Authorization. Delegate needed permissions for repos (or just repo's subtree) in single authz-file

> have also set the passwd files for every repos

Not needed and bad idea in common